# JQuery script for styling dropdown selects

Tags: jquery, forms, select, drop-down-menu, styles

I have found a few different scripts for styling form selects, but most of them are either outdated or very clunky. Any recommendations for good lightweight scripts to use?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, please?  For example, what sort of scripts have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to find a pretty clever CSS only solution:

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/